# Wordpress images showing bad on iOS

Tags: ios, wordpress, responsive-design, wordpress-theming

I have problem with iPhone. I have [HERE](http://zelenaruza.sk/3-apartman/) some photos of apartments. When I look on them through explorer on PC, everything is ok, same with Android phones, to the end Google Adults showing photos right when I try to simulate iPhone. But when I open site on iPhone, photos are rotated [CHECK HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRsdT.jpg). 
I don't know much about that theme, because I didn't make that site.

I just asking where can be problem, because I don't have idea.

Comment: Is that only on iphone the images are rotated to right?

Comment: Yes just Iphone. I tried it on Android and PC, but there it is ok. Only iPhone is rotated

Comment: side note: also rotated on safari macOS

Comment: So whole Apple is problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `style.css` file line 4331, You have this CSS which is causing issue. Please remove that if not needed to make it work

```
img {
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

**Edit: After you removed CSS**
[image: Screenshot after removing CSS]

Comment: Yes I deleted it, but it doesn't make difference. It is still rotated.

Comment: Its working  perfectly now, Can you test it. Try to clear your cache from browser

Comment: On iPhone it is still rotated

Comment: Can you check in CSS file, If `rotate` property is added somewhere else ?

Comment: Check in incognito mode of your browser on iphone or check in other phone once

Comment: there is no rotate in css

Comment: Can you check original Image you uploaded. I can see it as uploaded reverse (http://zelenaruza.sk/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/IMG_7119-e1503565939201.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for that hint. I didn't know it. Now it works perfectly, so thank you very much for your time and help. I appreciate it.

Comment: @MiroslavPančík.can you upvote and approve answer, so that it will be helpful to others as well

Answer (score -1):

here is the solution you can add it into your css file

```
 img {
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);

}
```

Comment: We don't need  to add, it is causing issue actually. Check my answer

Comment: add this line of code in css remove the old one it would be fine.

Comment: @RjAdii. But why should we add rotate, if user dont want to rotate the image at all?

Comment: just beacuse on iphone initial value is not set for the image in some case

Comment: But it will not rotate the image, if no property is set

Comment: @RjAdii I tried both of your codes and still nothing

Comment: link of your site and css